# Loop Python List : Conditional Value Change

Tags: python, pandas, list, loops, conditional-statements

I have a python list :

```
my_list = [0,0,0.5,0,0,0,0.4,0,0.6]
```

I want to replace all the 0 by the next higher value  than 0 in the list to obtain :

```
my_list = [0.5,0.5,0.5,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.6,0.6]
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: `pd.Series(my_list).replace(0, np.nan).bfill().tolist()`

Comment: @It_is_Chris this will not work for [0, 0, -8, 0, 6]

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, -8.2, 0.4, 0, 0.6]

hook = 0
for i, v in enumerate(my_list):
    if v > 0:
        for j in range(hook, i):
            if my_list[j] == 0:
                my_list[j] = v
        hook = i + 1
print(my_list)
# [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, -8.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.6]
```

### Edit2 (shorter)

```
my_list = [0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, -8.2, 0.4, 0, 0.6]

hook, last_index = 0, len(my_list)-1
for i, v in enumerate(reversed(my_list)):
    hook = v if v > 0 else hook
    my_list[last_index - i] = hook if v == 0 else v
print(my_list)
# [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, -8.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.6]
```

Answer (score -2):

Just iterate over the list backwards

```
def fill(my_list):
  last = len(my_list)-1
  last_val = my_list[last]
  for kk in range(last-1,-1,-1):
    if my_list[kk] == 0 and last_val > 0:
      my_list[kk] = last_val
    if my_list[kk] > 0:
      last_val = my_list[kk]
  return my_list
```

---

```
>>> fill([0, 0, -8, 0, 6])
[6, 6, -8, 6, 6]
```